# Setting SQS permissions, why is the principal not applied?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I call [setQueueAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/SetQueueAttributesRequest.html) on an existing queue with a `policy` that looks like below, aiming to allow the topic `my-topic` the action `SendMessage` on the queue `my-queue`. The policy is applied successfully except for the `principal` which remains `None` instead of `Everybody (*)`. Why is the `principal` not being applied?

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"d46625b6-b24e-4343-9f4e-773299fc7c56",
  "Statement":
  {
    "Sid":"SNStoSQS",
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Principal":"*",
    "Action":"sqs:SendMessage",
    "Resource":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:111111111111:my-queue",
    "Condition":
    {
      "ArnEquals":
      {
        "aws:SourceArn":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:609131769936:my-topic"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subscribing an Amazon SQS queue to an Amazon SNS topic via the Management Console, the following policy is automatically generated:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:my-queue/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Sid1111",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:my-queue",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:my-topic"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It looks like `Principal` field is slightly differently formatted.